# Javascript calling a passed function and params

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to repurpose a "legacy function" to pass a function with parameters into another function and get called. I've seen bits and pieces of what I'm looking for, but my arguments keep getting passed as a single string. This is the calling code - the 4th parameter (starts with '_delRideNew') is what I need to call.

```
MODAL.show("Confirm", "Are you sure you want to delete this ride?","Yes","_delRideNew('" + id + "','" + day + "','" + attuid + "')","No","MODAL.hide();")
```

Here is the MODAL.show code (using easyui):

```
MODAL.show = function(title, msg, okbtn, okcallback, canbtn, cancallback) {
if(arguments.length > 2) {
    $.messager.defaults.ok = okbtn;
    $.messager.defaults.cancel = canbtn;
}
else {
    $.messager.defaults.ok = "OK";
    $.messager.defaults.cancel = "Cancel";
}

if(arguments.length === 6) {
    var me = $.messager.confirm(title, msg, function(r) {

        if(r) {
            //parse out function and args
            var pos = okcallback.indexOf("(");
            var func = okcallback.substring(0,pos);
            var argss = okcallback.substring(pos,okcallback.length);
            argss = argss.replace("(", "");
            argss = argss.replace(")", ""); 

            var argArray = argss.split(",");

            window[func](argArray);
        }
        else {
            cancallback;
        }
    });
    me.window('move',{
        left:400,
        top:document.body.scrollTop+document.documentElement.scrollTop+200
    });     
}
else {
    confirm(msg, function(r) {
        if(r) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

}
The problem is when the window[func] gets called it passes the array as a single string here:

```
        function _delRideNew(id,day,attuid){
            alert(id); //shows all 3 params as a string
            var txtURL =  'delRide.cfm?tech_attuid=' + attuid + '&ride_date=#getParam("month")#/' + day + "/#getParam("year")#";
            SYS.loadScript(txtURL);
            status = txtURL;

        }
```

It's very much possible that I'm doing this completely wrong, but any help would be, well..helpful.

Comment: You should always pass callbacks as functions, not as to-be-evaled strings.

Comment: Can you expand on that a bit for me?

Comment: Do not pass that string that you would need to parse. Pass a function, just like you do to `$.messager.confirm(…)`, and you can simply invoke it without parsing any arguments or accessing `window` properties.